# CKEditor Scrollbar Position Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm Working on CKEditor. For now, I want to customize it someway.

I want the CKEditor scrollbar in left instead of right. How can I do this?

Comment: have you checked the docs? https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_configuration

Comment: But, they didn't said anything about what I'm searching

Comment: I don't think there is a built in plugin option. But you can achieve it with CSS. Check out this https://jsfiddle.net/esLn3sLv/2/

Comment: But in your example, you didn't use CKEditor.And sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Well, just apply those styles to the element that overflows in Ckeditor. Or post some fiddle or snippet in your question and we'll see.

Comment: lol scrollbar is navigator tools. Every application have scrollbar in the right side, is to strange to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib to have your own scrollbar :

https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

```
var Scrollbar = window.Scrollbar;

Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('<id>'), options);
```